# How is a must and filter interpreted together in elastich search bool query?

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

Hi I am just new to ES wanted to know that this type of queries are like a && queries ? must && filter

````
query : {
 must : { query if a field exists },
 filter : { query to filter some results}
}
}```
````

Answer (score 0):

The ElasticSearch documentation is really quite good and should not be overlooked.

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch//reference/current/query-filter-context.html

That answers your question with the details I will not provide here.

The portion of the query under the must, is scored, the quality of the match is taken into consideration in the ordering of the search results, and a score value is calculated and returned, indicating the quality of each match.

The portion of the query under the filter context does not do any scoring, and all matches are considered equal and treated as either a yes or a no.

Because the filter query is a yes or no, it is execute first, the must query is only executed on documents that matched the filter portion.  If there is part of your query that does not need scoring, such as a date or price range, the filter context will substantially improve the performance of the query.  If none of your query requires scoring, placing it all in the filter context will enhance performance.